# How to loop over class instance variables without calling methods?

Tags: python, class

In the following code example I'm trying to print a list of all instance variables by calling the `info()` method of my class.
That works so far but the problem is that looping over the instance variables `setup_method()` and `self.update_state()` is called also, because they seem to be class vars as well.

Is there an elegant way to prevent this?

```
import setup_method
import read_state

class Relay(object):
    """Simple class for a Relay"""

    def __init__(self, name, channel):
        self.name = name
        self.channel = channel
        self.state = None
        setup_method()
        self.update_state()

    def switch_low(self):
        print('low')
        self.update_state()

    def switch_high(self):
        print('high')
        self.update_state()

    def update_state(self):
        self.state = read_state()

    def info(self):
        print('\n'.join("%s: %s" % item for item in vars(self).items()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    relay_a = Relay('Generic Relay', channel=0)
    relay_a.info()
```

Comment: Consider to use `__dict__`.

Comment: @ZavenZareyan `vars(obj)` generally returns `obj.__dict__`

Comment: If you plan on updating the set of instance attributes so often that you feel the need to automate the definition of `info` like this, consider storing the values in a single *explicit* `dict` attribute. If not, I don't see that it is worth the effort: just hard-code a series of calls to `print`, one per attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All functions can be called. So, you just need to filter those out:

```
def info(self):
    print('\n'.join("%s: %s" % item 
                    for item in vars(self).items()
                    if not hasattr(item, '__call__')
         ))
```

This will output only the non-callable attributes of the class.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what i was looking for.